# I'm using Windows 10 currently, when I try to open any Microsoft office 365 applications such as word or excel I get the following error

Tags: office365

Error saying the configuration registry database is corrupt.

[Here is the error that comes when I open Microsoft Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmHuU.png)

Comment: Does this question have something with *programming*, or is it entirely about *using* programs? If the latter is the case, I'd vote for migration (and possibly editing afterwards, but not here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall and Reinstall MS Word.

Follow the thread below, it seems that's the only solution.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/configuration-registry-database-is-corrupt/da0df98f-8f12-4bfb-a8c4-532ff9b57af7